# SceneKit objects collide at their bounding box instead of along the mesh

Tags: ios, 3d, swift3, physics, scenekit

I'm using "DAE" model as SCNGeometry.

[image: Half of TUBE]

Trying to use it as physics body shape:

```
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "art.scnassets/half", withExtension: "dae")
    let sceneSource = SCNSceneSource(url: url!, options: nil)
    let tubeGeometry = (sceneSource?.entryWithIdentifier("Cube-mesh", withClass: SCNGeometry.self ))! as SCNGeometry
    
    tubeNode = SCNNode(geometry: tubeGeometry)
    tubeNode.position = SCNVector3(0, 1, 0)
    tubeNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3Make(1.5, 2, 0)

    let tubeShape = SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: tubeGeometry, options: nil)
    let tubeBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .static, shape: tubeShape)
    tubeNode.physicsBody = tubeBody
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(tubeNode)
```

Do not perceive geometrical object properties (edges, faces, etc.).
Perceives the cube as it seems.
So as a result, the ball collides with an invisible plane that is not my object, but must fall inward as on screenshot below:
[image: scene]

Any ideas / advices why is it?
Please help me to fix that problem...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to configure your physics body shape to "SCNPhysicsShapeTypeConcavePolyhedron" (defaults to convex). You can use the SCNView's debugOptions to visualize the physics shapes